# mobx react integration not working. Uncaught Error Make sure it is provided by some Provider

Tags: observable, mobx, mobx-react

I am really new to Mobx and intermediate with react, I am working on an app to pull videos from some api. The idea is that its a single page with search for videos option and a drop down to sort the videos.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import VideoHeader from "./VideoHeader";
import VideoSection from "./VideoSection";

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section id="main">
        <VideoHeader /> <!--static component -->
        <VideoSection /> <!-- Video section containing other search Section with input and sort drop down-->
      </section>
    );
  }
}

//VideoSection.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SearchSection from "./SearchSection";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player/lazy";
import VideoSearchService from "../service/VideoSearchService";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";

class VideoSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchvideos = this.fetchvideos.bind(this);
    this.renderPopularVideos = this.renderPopularVideos.bind(this);
    this.createIFrame = this.createIFrame.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      searchText: "latest unboxing videos",
      pvideos: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //var data = {
    // searchText: this.state.searchText,
    //};
    //this.fetchvideos(data);
    this.props.VideoStore.fetchVideosAsync();
  }

  fetchvideos(data) {
    VideoSearchService.searchVideoOf(data)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          searchText: data.searchText,
          pvideos: response.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.target);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="py-20 bg-gray-100">
        <div className="container mx-auto px-4">
          <div className="pb-9 text-center border-b border-black border-opacity-5">
            <div className="relative">
              <h2 className="text-5xl font-heading font-heading font-medium text-center">
                <span>Discover {this.state.searchText}</span>
              </h2>
              <span className="md:absolute md:right-0 md:bottom-3 text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium">{this.state.pvideos.length} videos found</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <SearchSection onChangeSearchText={this.fetchvideos} />
          <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-24">{this.renderPopularVideos()}</div>
          <div className="text-center">
            <a className="inline-block bg-orange-300 hover:bg-orange-400 text-white font-bold font-heading py-6 px-8 rounded-md uppercase" href="#">
              Show More
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }

  renderPopularVideos() {
    //const { pvideos } = this.state;
    //const descvideos = [...pvideos].sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.publishedAt) - Date.parse(a.publishedAt));
    return (
      <div className="w-full px-3">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3">{this.createIFrame(this.state.pvideos)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  createIFrame(pvideos) {
    const results = [];
    //console.log("Creating iFrame for videos ",pvideos);
    pvideos.forEach((video, i) => {
      results.push(
        <div className="w-full sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 px-3 mb-8" key={video.id}>
          <div className="p-6 bg-gray-50">
            <div className="relative bg-gray-50 aspect-w-9 aspect-h-16">
              <ReactPlayer url={this.toEmbedURL(video.watchURL)} controls={true} width="420px" height="280px" />
              <div className="px-6 pb-6 mt-8">
                <h6 className="mb-2 text-sm font-bold">{video.title}</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return results;
  }

  toEmbedURL(watchUrl) {
    return watchUrl.replace("/watch?v=", "/embed/");
  }
}
export default inject("VideoStore")(observer(VideoSection));
```

Now my VideoStore :

```
import { observable, runInAction, decorate } from "mobx";
import VideoSearchService from "./VideoSearchService";

class VideoStore {
  constructor() {
    this.video = new VideoSearchService();
  }
  videos = [];
  searchText = "lastest videos";
  sortOn = 0; //0: Popular, 1: Newest, 2: Likes or ratings, 3: Most commented
  status = "initial";

  fetchVideosAsync = async () => {
    try {
      var data = {
        searchText: this.searchText,
      };
      const response = await this.video.searchVideoOf(data);
      runInAction(() => {
        this.videos = response.data;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.status = "error";
      });
    }
  };
}

decorate(VideoStore, {
  videos: observable,
  searchText: observable,
  sortOn: observable,
  status: observable,
});

export default new VideoStore();
```

[Uncaught Error: MobX injector: Store 'VideoStore' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3ciI.png)

SearchSection.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class SearchSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText: props.searchText,
      sortOn: 0, //0: Popular, 1: Newest, 2: Likes or ratings, 3: Most commented
      pvideos: props.pvideos,
    };
  }

  handleSearch = () => {
    var data = {
      searchText: this.state.searchText,
    };
    console.log(data);
    this.props.onChangeSearchText(data);
  };

  handleSort = (event) => {
    this.setState({ sortOn: event.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.sortOn);
  };

  render() {
    return (
          <div className="flex flex-wrap py-5 mb-14 xl:mb-16 border-b border-black border-opacity-10 items-center">
            <div className="flex mr-auto mb-10 lg:mb-0 items-center pl-8 bg-white rounded-lg">
              <span className="mr-3">
                <svg width="18" height="19" viewBox="0 0 18 19" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M17.5 17.6719L12.5042 12.4961" stroke="black" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                  <path d="M7.27524 14.4082C10.8789 14.4082 13.8002 11.486 13.8002 7.88134C13.8002 4.27666 10.8789 1.35449 7.27524 1.35449C3.67159 1.35449 0.750244 4.27666 0.750244 7.88134C0.750244 11.486 3.67159 14.4082 7.27524 14.4082Z" stroke="black" strokeMiterlimit="10" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
                </svg>
              </span>
              <input className="border-0 focus:ring-transparent focus:outline-none" type="search" defaultValue={searchText} onChange={(event) => this.setState({ searchText: event.target.value })} />
              <button className="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 bg-orange-300 hover:bg-orange-400 rounded-md" onClick={this.handleSearch}>
                <svg width="7" height="12" viewBox="0 0 7 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M4.125 6.00252L0 1.87752L1.17801 0.699219L6.48102 6.00252L1.17801 11.3058L0 10.1275L4.125 6.00252Z" fill="white"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full sm:w-1/3 lg:w-1/5 py-2 sm:px-3">
              <div className="w-full sm:w-auto mb-4 sm:mb-0 mr-5">
                <select value={this.state.sortOn} onChange={this.handleSort} className="pl-8 py-4 bg-white text-lg border border-gray-200 focus:ring-blue-300 focus:border-blue-300 rounded-md">
                  <option value="0">Sort by newest</option>
                  <option value="1">Sort by rating</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong or where to get help, also I don't want to use decorators so latest MobX-react integration with class components. How this is glued.. how can I link searchText (input box) value everytime it changes in SearchSection plus that drop down also inside SearchSection.
How to inject observable (without decorators) inside SearchSection.. how to pass the value of searchText (query) from searchSection to the VideoSection to trigger re-fetching of videos from Store and also sort it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself the thing I was trying is to not use any decorators earlier as Mobx uses in all the online tutorials. Once I enabled decorators locally through react rewired script. I changed my code to what i see online and now everything works.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import VideoHeader from "./VideoHeader";
import VideooSection from "./VideoSection";
import { store } from "../service/VideoStore";
import { inject, observer, Provider } from "mobx-react";

@inject("store")
@observer
class Main extends Component {
 render() {
   const { store } = this.props;
   return (
  <section id="main">
    <VideoHeader />
    <VideoSection onSubmit={store.fetchVideosAsync} />
  </section>
);
 }
}

 export function VideoApp() {
 return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Main />
   </Provider>
 );
 }
```